# Python. как показать последние 50 строк в массиве?

Tags: python, numpy

Есть огромный массив. Разделенный reshape(-1,50,3), какой командой можно показать последние 50 строк?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`arr[-N:]` - даст выборку из последних N элементов arr.